# Both of Flutter audio service and FCM need to change the android name. How can I integrate it?

Tags: android, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-manifest, audio-service

**Flutter audio service need to change the `android:name` like this**

`android:name="com.ryanheise.audioservice.AudioServiceActivity"`

[package](https://pub.dev/packages/audio_service)   and   [documation](https://suragch.medium.com/background-audio-in-flutter-with-audio-service-and-just-audio-3cce17b4a7d?sk=0837a1b1773e27a4f879ff3072e90305)

**Firebase Cloud Messaging also need to change the `android:name` like this**

`android:name=".Application"`

[package](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging)   and   [documation](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/overview/#3-android-integration)

How can I make change to use both packages in my application?

### Edited

Now I have solved the problem by upgrading flutter version but I would like to know how do I make change if I meet a situation like my question. If anyone has a solution for my question, let me know it please.

Comment: According to the last link, if you're setting the `android:name=".Application"` that means you're using Android embedding v1. Is there a reason why you can't use v2? Is it because you are pinned to an older Flutter version < 1.12 for some reason?

Comment: @RyanHeise 
Thank for comment!
Yes, I see that it doesn't need other additional features for flutter v2. But I would like to know how do I make change if I meet a situation like my question.

This project is dependent on flutter 1.7.0. Now  I have upgraded to flutter 3.0.5.

I have solved the problem but I still have this question. So I am asking in here. If you have a solution for my question, let me know it please.
Thank!

Comment: The exact situation you describe in your question is already solved by yourself, because probably nobody should be using a version of Flutter older than 1.12. The answer is "upgrade"! You might want to consider writing up an answer to your question and marking it as the accepted answer.

Comment: As for the hypothetical question of whether you might run into a similar situation again, I think you should create a question with a specific example, because the answer will depend on the specifics.

Comment: Yes, but with a "hypothetical" question. I'm not answering that, like I just explained. My reply to you is therefore the same as before: (copy and paste):

"As for the hypothetical question of whether you might run into a similar situation again, I think you should create a question with a specific example, because the answer will depend on the specifics."